# TortoiseSVN shows head revision instead of revision specified in URL

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

1. Open TortoiseSVN Repository Browser
2. Enter an URL (of a file or directory, e.g.:

   http://svn.server/repository/File.txt
3. Enter an older revision number (e.g. 8093 )
4. Right click on a file or directory >> "Copy URL to clipboard" (for above example

   http://svn.server/repository/File.txt?r=8093 is got)
5. Paste URL got recently into the Repo Browser's navigation bar, press
6. Check "Revision:" at right, it will show "HEAD" instead of specified revision number (8093)

Is there any way getting an URL that navigates the Repo Browser to a desired revision ?

Answer (score 1):

The url format `url?r=revision` requires that the svn server is at least at version 1.8.0 or later when used in a web browser.

For the TortoisSVN repo browser however the format is different: use
http://svn.server/repository/file.txt@8093
for that.

Comment: Isn't it [1.6](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.browsing.syntax)?

Comment: Hello. It is Tortoise 1.8.1 and the server is 1.8